# Stamp of electrical department on letter head of recommendation letter

Tags: recommendation-letter

My referee is a pioneer of my university in my home country.  I am applying for PhD in Australia. My referee has signed the letter of recommendation in hardcopy form but he hasn't put a stamp of his name on it saying that letter head needs no stamp. I have mentioned on letter head that he is Professor and Trustee.  I have asked electrical department to put department stamp on it and they agreed. In this scenario is it likely that my chosen university in Australia may question why the pioneer and professor hasn't put his own stamp? Is it likely that the Australian university would contact my referee for it? Note that I am applying for a highly competitive scholarship in Australia.

Comment: When I assess PhD applications, I rarely notice the stamp on referee letters.  I tend to focus more on a student's transcripts, which must have an official stamp.

Comment: What's a "stamp"?

Comment: How exactly does a stamp help? I mean laser engravers are very common (you can find them in libraries... and 2 in my workshop), and laser engraving rubber is easily available. Faking a stamp takes literally 10 minutes of design work and 10-15 minutes of laser time, neither of which requires any specialist skill and cost is less than 20 euros.

Answer (score 12):

Australian universities do not use or expect stamps.  However, they may be familiar with the practices of universities in Asia and notice inconsistencies.  I suggest this is unimportant.

Comment: What do you mean by inconsistency here? Do you mean inconsistency regarding department stamp and not professor and trustee stamp on lor?

Comment: No, I mean they will have seen hundreds of similar documents and will know what the documents usually look like.

Answer (score 2):

I'm at a UK University and we don't have individual stamps, nor do we put any official stamp on reference letters. I've written dozens of recommendation letters for students applying to Australian Universities and none have had a stamp. Almost all of those students were admitted, many with significant funding. Listen to your Prof, you're fine.

Comment: The problem is that my another referee who is associate professor in another university has put his own stamp, while professor has not.

Comment: I don't see how that is a problem. Again, Australia does not use personal stamps so they won't notice either the presence or absence of a personal stamp.